# How to get the image URL from Structure Group Metadata using C# TBB

Tags: templating, content-manager, metadata, structuregroups, template-building-blocks

I have created a Structure group Metadata having image field. when I try to read the image url, I am getting the TCM ID.

```
ItemFields metadataFields = new ItemFields(objSG.Metadata, objSG.MetadataSchema);
foreach (ItemField metadataField in metadataFields)
{
   if (metadataField.Name == SchemaConstant.StructureGroupMetadataSchema.Image)
   {    
     elmSG.SetAttribute(Image, metadataField.ToString());
   }
}
```

**Result**: I am getting the value:

- image="Component tcm:720-107060"

Comment: Images don't have URLs on the CM side. Your template determines the URL when it publishes the image

Answer (score 2):

Images do not have a URL until they are published, as mentioned by @Nuno.

In your code you'll need to publish the binaries to get a URL you can use either the AddBinary or the PublishBinary method to publish binaries. I'd recommend AddBinary, as shown below:

```
ItemFields metadataFields = new ItemFields(objSG.Metadata, objSG.MetadataSchema);
foreach (ItemField metadataField in metadataFields)
{
   if (metadataField.Name == SchemaConstant.StructureGroupMetadataSchema.Image)
   {    
     //Add Image to package to be published
     var publishedImage = engine.AddBinary(metadataField.value);
     elmSG.SetAttribute(Image, publishedImage.Url);
   }
}
```

Additional options and parameters for the AddBinary function can be found in the documentation here: https://sdl.dist.sdlmedia.com/Distributions/?o=3E760DAB-B7EF-45DD-9D23-6BDA0B37538C